# why my program first executes function addmarkers() - not addAddresstoMap()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, callback, google-maps-api-2

I have a function LoadXML() in which after a ajax call to the server I've got an array with 100 addresses type string;

Also here we call the function extractAddressed()with the function `addmarkers` as callback;

```
function loadXMLDoc(l)
    {    
      //making ajax call to the server to get the addresses

    arrayMyAddresses.push(rec[i][8] + "," + rec[i][10]);

    extractAddresses(addmarkerss);

    }
```

Here is `extractAddresses` function which send a part of the addresses which i want to geocode using the `getLocations` method which performs asynchronous call to the google servers

```
function extractAddresses(callback)
    {    alert (startman);
          i=startman;

        while  (i<startman+intPageSize)
        {
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
            //alert(arrayMyAddresses[i]);
            geocoder.getLocations(arrayMyAddresses[i], addAddressToMap);
            i++;

        }

        //callback();
        setTimeout(callback,300);


    }
```

Here you may also see  the function `addAddresstoMap` which handle the response from google servers and creates an array of gmarkers!

```
function addAddressToMap(response) 
    {

        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) 

        {
           alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
        } 

        else 
        {   

            place = response.Placemark[0];
            point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1], place.Point.coordinates[0]);
            var marker = new GMarker(point);
            batch.push(marker);
            //alert ("batchaddaddresstomap " + batch.length);

        } 


    }
```

And at last `addmarkerss`() function which add the array of Gmarkers to the map;

```
function addmarkerss()
    {

        // alert("batchf: " + batch.length);         
         mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
         mgr.addMarkers(batch,13);
         mgr.refresh();

    }
```

So this is how the programme should work 
when i call `extractAddresses` and i give one by one the addresses for geocoding to `addAddresstoMap` function and they are dynamically added to an array of type Gmarker;
when I'm ready with this i call addmarkers() to put the markers on my map;

**But what does it make actually**

when i call `extractaddresses` it somehow goes first to `addmarkers` function it sees that `banch` array is empty and it doesn't load any markers;
When i put `setTimeout(callback,300);`and i postpone the execution of `addmarkers` everything works.

---

**What may be the reason. And i also want to ask if the problem is here: 
Although it is true that a callback function will execute last if it is placed last in the function, this will not always appear to happen. For example, if the function included some kind of asynchronous execution (**like an Ajax call as it's my case***), **then the callback would execute after the asynchronous action begins, but possibly before it finishes**. is it my case? also how can i solve my problem without `settimeout`*

Comment: You're using the deprecated Google Maps API v2, which will stop working May 2013.  Suggest you upgrade to API v3 asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If the function included some kind of asynchronous execution (like an Ajax call as it's my case), then the callback would execute after the asynchronous action begins, but possibly before it finishes. **is it my case?***

It is the case, geocoding is an asynchronous process.

You must  call **`addmarkerss()`** inside  **`addAddressToMap()`** when **`batch`** reaches the expected length(the last geocoding-request has been finished)

Comment: Thank you Dr.Molle! I supposethat was the case but i wanted to be sure. The problem now is that I don't know for sure the length of batch - it may be 8, 9, 10 because sometimes the function  may not succeed in geocoding the address! what can i do

Comment: You may setup a variable where you store the expected number of markers depending on your XML. In addAddressToMap() **always** decrease this variable(no matter if the geocoding was successfull or not). When the variable is 0, the last geocoding-request has been finished and you can call `addMarkerss()`